# Click RecyclerView - Item

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, click

Necesito hacer click en un item de un RecyclerView pero al tratar de hacerlo me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.zero.test.Interface.ItemClickListener.onClick(android.view.View, int, boolean)' on a null object reference

Lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente:

Creé una interface de la siguiente forma:

```
   public interface ItemClickListener {
    void onClick(View view,int position,boolean isLongClick);
   }
```

Luego de eso creé una clase de Java para me

```
public class MenuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView txtNombre;
    public ImageView imgWallpaper;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public MenuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtNombre = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.NombreWallpaper);
        imgWallpaper = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_imagen);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

     public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
         this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
     }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);
        Log.d("Mensaje","Test");

    }
}
```

Y por último en mi main, me conecto a una base de datos en firebase y muestro unas imágenes de la siguiente forma:

//Declaración de variables globales

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference category = database.getReference("Wallpaper");

    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<wallpaperClass, MenuViewHolder> adapter;
```

//Código principal

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions <wallpaperClass> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<wallpaperClass>()
                        .setQuery(category,wallpaperClass.class)
                        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                        .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<wallpaperClass, MenuViewHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull wallpaperClass model) {
                holder.txtNombre.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getLinkwall()).into(holder.imgWallpaper);
            }


            @NonNull
            @Override
            public MenuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_item,parent,false);
                return new MenuViewHolder(v);
            }
        };

        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Todo funciona muy bien, se muestran las imágenes como corresponden pero cuando le doy clic a una imagen me saca de la app.

Agradezco a todos desde ya por su ayuda.

saludos..

Solución:
Agregue este codigo a onBindViewHolder, valide el click desde esa área y listo..
gracias a todos.

```
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MenuViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final wallpaperClass model) {
                holder.txtNombre.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.get().load(model.getLinkwall()).into(holder.imgWallpaper);

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Link: " + model.getLinkwall().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        /*Intent Wallpaper = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),homeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(Wallpaper);*/
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: si te e es de ayuda, te dejo este repo mio que hice para entender bien RecyclerView todo comentado el codigo https://github.com/gastsail/EntendiendoRecyclerView

Comment: Hola, ya pudiste solucionarlo?